# How to delete rows before Today's date in a sharepoint list from the pnppowershell module?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I use a Sharepoint list with 4 columns. The first column contains a date.
What I would like is a ps-script that deletes every row before Todays date.
Is that possible? This is what i got so far:

```
connect-pnponline -url xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -Credential $credential
```

Remove-PnPListItem -List "my-list" -Identity ($TheItemId)

PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test the PnP script in TEST area before applying to PROD

```
#Get the items that are older than Today
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Query "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='StartDate'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Leq></Where></Query></View>"


$items.Count

foreach($item in $items) 
  {
    write-host "removing item: " $item.Id

    Remove-PnPListItem -List "Contact" -Identity $item.Id -Force
    
  }
```